# Looking for correct Javascript IIFE pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a large codebase and came across this file with just the following in it:

```
window.hasTouch = (function() {
    // will return 'true' if user is visiting with a touch-capable device
    return ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
});
```

Then window.hasTouch is called in the following way in another file:

```
hasTouch = window.hasTouch();
```

My question is, sometimes in console, calling it with () returns an error of:

```
TypeError: boolean is not a function
```

And then when I run it just as "hasTouch = window.hasTouch" (parens omitted), it returns true/false like I want.

Can someone please clarify in this setup what's ideal way to call window.hasTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you want `window.hasTouch` to be a bool instead of a function you can simply do:

```
window.hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

Otherwise, you can evaluate the anonymous function immediately:

```
window.hasTouch = (function() {
    // will return 'true' if user is visiting with a touch-capable device
    return ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
})(); // <-- note the extra parens
```

Answer (score 1):

By assigning `hasTouch` globally you overwrite `window.hasTouch` so that function is lost. If you want to avoid this, use `var hasTouch = ...` inside a function.

Also, your code is not an IIFE - you just assign the function to `window.hasTouch`. An IIFE would have `()` after the function definition to call it immediately and assign its return value instead.

Comment: I suspected it's not an IIFE, but what about the function being completely wrapped in parens, can you clarify what that's doing then (if not making it an IIFE)

Comment: @RV—In javascript, "(" and ")" are [*punctuators*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.7), i.e. punctuation marks. They are used to group things. In the case of `(function(){...})` they have no effect on evaluation. They are used in an IIFE to create a function expression (where the name can be omitted) rather than a function declaration. Another pattern is `!function(){}()`. Putting `()` after a function reference indicates a parameter list, and a function reference followed by a (possibly empty) parameter list causes the function to be called and passed the parameters. HTH :-)